# JAXB xjc - [ERROR] Unexpected <xs:schema> appears at line 2 column 101

Tags: xml, jakarta-ee, jaxb

I'm an jaxb beginner. I am trying to run xjc to generate java classes from a schema. I have a sample .xsd file with following format at top of file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="urn:iso:std:iso:yakity:schmakity" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xs:element name="Document" type="Document"/>
```

I am following this tutorial as a guide

[jee5 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19316-01/819-3669/bnazf/index.html)

I run the following command to try and parse teh schema and generate java classes

```
 xjc -nv /home/tommy/xsds/my.xsd
```

but it always complains about schema tag, i would have assumed schema has to be here?

```
[ERROR] Unexpected <xs:schema> appears at line 2 column 101
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The namespace assigned to the `xs` prefix is wrong for an XML Schema.  It should be `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` and not `urn:iso:std:iso:yakity:schmakity`.

If you want `urn:iso:std:iso:yakity:schmakity` to be the namespace for the XML documents that conform to this XML schema, then you should set it up as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    targetNamespace="urn:iso:std:iso:yakity:schmakity" 
    xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:yakity:schmakity" 
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks Blaise, that fixed it. I have one question the real namespace supplied in this xml is of form xs="urn:iso:std:iso:yakity:schmakity" I just edited last part to be "yakity schmakity". It is an ISO generated schema. Why do i need to make this change?

Comment: @user1843591 - XML documents have a 2 part name (local name + namespace).  In order to be recognized as an XML schema the nodes need to be in the proper namespace.  The `targetNamespace` is how to specify the namespace for documents is configured.